# AntTweakBar.dll missing error in VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, directx

I came across AntTweakBar Fraemwork and was very impressed.So i thought of integrating it to my program as well.

I add the include directory to the include path in the project properties
I also added the path to the lib in the library directory in project..

Even after adding AntTweakBar.lib to the input Linker..

I keep getting this error while debugging

***The Program cannot start as AntTweakBar.dll is missing from the computer ***

I dont know what to do...

Please do help me out here

Plaese....

Waiting eagerly for an answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to extend the `PATH` environment variable with the directory where that `AntTweakBar.dll` file is actually installed.

The error message you get indicates, that the dynamic linker isn't able to find and load it when your program starts.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply...But the PATH varaible is used by netbeans for the java directory.   I couldnt find any other path varaible that pointed to the dll. Is there any other name for it..Please do help me out ....                               Thanks

Comment: @user3797103 You should just set it on system environment level. It can contain more than one directories separated with `;`.